# Unwanted Jump to interrupt MPLAB X IDE v.3.30

Tags: c, assembly, embedded

I am new to programming on micro controllers and I am  trying to write a timer program for the PICLF1571. Every time it wakes from sleep, it's supposed to write to the flash memory. When I debug it with the simulation, it's able to write once, but once it loops the program gets stuck in the interrupt routine. If I comment out the Interrupt routine, the simulation jumps to another place or goes to 0x00.
The only time I see the program get stuck is when the function flash_write is used.

What could be some causes for interrupts to occur if no flags are triggered?

pin setup

```
void init(void){
    ANSELA = 0x0;           //|-> Pin setup
    TRISA = 0x0;
    TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 1;
    PORTA = 0x0;
    LATA = 0x0;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;     //|-> Interrupt setup
    INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;
    IOCAP = 0x0;
    IOCAPbits.IOCAP5 = 0;
    INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0;
    IOCAF = 0x0;
    IOCAFbits.IOCAF5 = 0;
    WDTCONbits.SWDTEN = 1;  //|-> Watchdog Timer setup
    WDTCONbits.WDTPS = 0b00001;// reconfigure for correct speed
    //currently        0b10001
}
```

main

```
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include "init.h"
#include "Interrupt.h"
#include "flash.h"

int main(void){
    init();
    unsigned short ad = 1;
    unsigned short f = 0x3FFF;
    unsigned short a = 0x0000;
    unsigned short ret = 0x0000;
    flash_erase(0x0000);
    while(1) {
        asm("sleep");
        flash_write(a,f);

        //flash_erase(a);
        //flash_read1(a,&ret);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

flash_write function. Instructions based on flowchart in datasheet

```
void flash_write(unsigned short addr, unsigned short data){
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0; //||]->start write
    PMCON1bits.CFGS = 0;//||]
    PMADRH = (unsigned char)((addr >> 8) & 0xFF);
    PMADRL = (unsigned char)(addr & 0xFF);
    PMCON1bits.FREE = 0;//||]->enable write
    PMCON1bits.LWLO = 1;//||]
    PMCON1bits.WREN = 1;//||]
    PMDATH = (unsigned char)((data >> 8) & 0xFF);
    PMDATL = (unsigned char)(data & 0xFF);
    PMCON1bits.LWLO = 0;
    PMCON2 = 0x55;      //||]->unlock sequence
    PMCON2 = 0xAA;      //||]
    PMCON1bits.WR = 1;  //||]
    NOP();              //||]
    NOP();              //||]
    PMCON1bits.WREN = 0;//]->end write 
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
    asm("RETURN");
}
```

interrupt routine

```
#include <xc.h>
void interrupt button(void){
    if (INTCONbits.IOCIE == 1 && IOCAFbits.IOCAF5 == 1 ){
        int time = 0;
        while (PORTAbits.RA5 == 1){//RA5 in sim never changes. always 0
            time++;
            if (time >= 20000 && PORTAbits.RA5 == 1){
                LATA = 0x0;
                asm("NOP");
                break;
           }
            if ( time < 20000 && PORTAbits.RA5 == 0){
                asm("NOP");
                break;
           }
        }
        IOCAF = 0x0;
        INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0;
        asm("RETFIE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean PIC12F1571?  There is no device PICLF1571.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0000h is the reset vector address; once written, subsequent resets will jump to 0x3fff, which is not a valid address on a device with only 0x3ff words of flash.  Note that since 0x3fff is the erased state of flash memory, the write in this case actually has no effect that is not already caused by the erase alone.

Also understand that, the PIC12 flash memory is word-write/row-erase, and a row is 16 words.  So the erase operation will wipe out the entire vector table and the start of the program area too.  You are essentially modifying the code, but not in a manner than makes any sense (if it makes sense at all).

You should reserve an area of flash using appropriate linker directives and well away from the vector table (probably the entire last row at 0x3f0, to prevent the linker locating code in the space you want to write at run time.

Another issue is that the flash cell endurance on PIC12F1571 is only 10000 erase/write cycles - are you sure you want to write to the same address every time the device boots?  If you "stripe" the reserved row and write to each of the 16 words in turn before erasing the row and restarting, you will increase endurance to 160000 cycles.  Add more rows to get greater endurance.  Since erased flash has a value 0x3fff (14 bit words), to find the "current value" you need to scan the reserved row(s) for the last value that is not 0x3fff (0x3fff is implicitly therefore not a valid actual value).